# Appending values to list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I am trying to append dependent values to a list as below and running into a keyerror...i have the expected output below..can anyone provide inputs on what is wrong here?

```
'''
Current output without "+=" in internal_dep[num] +=dep_gerrit :-
{'313137': '12345', '99999': '', '34567': '99999', '12345': '34567'}

EXPECTED OUTPUT:-

{'313137': ['12345', '34567': '99999']}

'''
def  findinternaldep(num):
    if num == '313137':
        output ='12345'
    if num == '12345':
        output = '34567'
    if num == '34567':
        output = '99999'
    if num == '99999':
        output = ''
    return output


master_gerrit = ['313137']
internal_dep={}
for num in master_gerrit:
    while True:
        print "NUM"
        print num
        (dep_gerrit)=findinternaldep(num)
        internal_dep[num] +=dep_gerrit
        num = dep_gerrit
        if dep_gerrit == '':
            break
print internal_dep
```

ERROR:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_internal.py", line 34, in <module>
    internal_dep[num] +=dep_gerrit
KeyError: '313137'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to append to the list before its key exists in the dictionary. The easiest way to address this is to make your `internal_dep` dictionary a `collections.defaultdict`. Then, if the key doesn't already exist, a default value (which you can specify) will be created automatically.

```
import collections
internal_dep = collections.defaultdict(list)
```

Also note that `+=` is equivalent to `list.extend` rather than `list.append`, so you should use one of the following:

```
internal_dep[num] += [dep_gerrit]   # or
internal_dep[num].append(dep_gerrit)
```

What you have won't give you an error, but it won't do what you want, either!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following approach. Basically check if the dict already has the key and if not add a new key else append to the list.

```
if internal_dep.has_key(num):
    internal_dep[num].append(dep_gerrit)
else:
    internal_dep[num]=[dep_gerrit,]
```

With this change, your overall code would look like:

```
mmaster_gerrit = ['313137']
internal_dep={}
for num in master_gerrit:
    while True:
        print "NUM"
        print num
        (dep_gerrit)=findinternaldep(num)
        print "DEP_GERRIT"
        print dep_gerrit
        #print master_gerrit
        #print dep_gerrit
        #print depgerrit_status
        if internal_dep.has_key(num):
            internal_dep[num].append(dep_gerrit)
        else:
            internal_dep[num]=[dep_gerrit,]
        num = dep_gerrit
        if dep_gerrit == '':
            break
print internal_dep
```

Comment: above is not working..its not giving the expected output...did it work for you?

Comment: @user2125827 I think I misunderstood your expected answer. But the output you want {'313137': ['12345', '34567': '99999']} is not a valid python data struct. Maybe you want to modify it to something that Python accepts and then we can modify this solution further.

Comment: am not sure why its not a valid construct...my idea is to create a dictionary of lists...

Comment: sure but 313137's corresponding value is a list of a string (ie '12345') and a dict (ie 34567': '99999'). I believe all elements of a list should be of same type.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the version that worked for me

```
list = ['313137','253036']
internal_dep={}
for num in list:
    master_gerrit = num
    while True:
        print "NUM"
        print num
        (dep_gerrit)=findinternaldep(num)
        print "DEP_GERRIT"
        print dep_gerrit
        #print master_gerrit
        print dep_gerrit

        if internal_dep.has_key(master_gerrit):
            internal_dep[master_gerrit].append(dep_gerrit)
        else:
            internal_dep[num]=[dep_gerrit,]
        if dep_gerrit == '':
            break
        num = dep_gerrit
print internal_dep
```

OUTPUT:-
{'313137': ['12345', '34567', '99999', ''], '253036': ['']}